# emit state from listening to stream inside a bloc doesn't work

Tags: flutter, state, bloc, flutter-bloc, dio

Im using `StreamController` to track the progress of uploading an image using `Dio`, so when i sink a value in my stream i trigger an event to emit new state to rebuild my widget, the problem is it does not emit new state.

This is the code from my `ChatBloc`

```
class Chat extends Bloc<ChatEvent, ChatState> {
  final StreamController<FileDetails> uploadStream =
      StreamController<FileDetails>();

  Chat(this.chatUseCases, this.chat)
      : super(const SingleChatState()) {
    on<ChatEmitUploadList>(_emitUploadList);

    /// listen to changes form upload stream
    uploadStream.stream.listen((event) {
      List<FileDetails> details = state.fileDetailsList;
      details
          .firstWhereOrNull((element) => element.id == event.id)!
          .percentage = event.percentage;
      add(SingleChatEvent.emitUploadList(fileDetails: event));
    });
  }
}

  FutureOr<void> _emitUploadList(
      ChatEmitUploadList event, Emitter<SingleChatState> emit) {
    print('emit once');
    List<FileDetails> details = List.from(state.fileDetailsList);
    details
        .firstWhereOrNull((element) => element.id == event.fileDetails.id)!
        .percentage = event.fileDetails.percentage;
    emit(state.copyWith(fileDetailsList: details));
  }
```

This is my `BlocBuilder`

```
class UploadingWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const UploadingWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocBuilder<ChatBloc, ChatState>(
      builder: (context, state) {
        if (state.status == SingleChatStatus.uploadingFiles) {
          return Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.white, borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.r)),
            margin: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
            child: CustomScrollView(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              slivers: [
                SliverGrid.builder(
                  gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithMaxCrossAxisExtent(
                      maxCrossAxisExtent: 100),
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) => Material(
                    child: SizedBox(
                      height: 100,
                      width: 100,
                      child: Center(
                        child: Text(
                            state.fileDetailsList[index].percentage.toString()),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  itemCount: state.fileDetailsList.length,
                )
              ],
            ),
          );
        }
        return const SizedBox.shrink();
      },
    );
  }
}
```

This is my method in `Dio`

```
final response = await dio.post(BASE_TEST+sendMessageEndPoint,data: data,
onSendProgress: (count, total) {
  if(file!=null){
    String fileName = file.path.toString().split('/').last;
    double percentage = (count / total * 100).toDouble();
    uploadStream.sink.add(FileDetails(id: file.path!, percentage: percentage,file: file));
  }
},);
```

This is my debug console

```
[log] onEvent -- ChatBloc, ChatEvent.emitUploadList(fileDetails: Instance of 'FileDetails')
[log] onEvent -- ChatBloc, ChatEvent.emitUploadList(fileDetails: Instance of 'FileDetails')
[log] onEvent -- ChatBloc, ChatEvent.emitUploadList(fileDetails: Instance of 'FileDetails')
[log] onEvent -- ChatBloc, ChatEvent.emitUploadList(fileDetails: Instance of 'FileDetails')
[log] onEvent -- ChatBloc, ChatEvent.emitUploadList(fileDetails: Instance of 'FileDetails')
```

Comment: why don't you use `forEach` / `onEach` methods of [Emitter](https://pub.dev/documentation/bloc/latest/bloc/Emitter-class.html) object?

Comment: can you explain farther pls

Comment: check `Emitter` class official documentation - i posted it above

Comment: i tried it, still no progress, the bloc builder itself does not rebuild

Comment: check [How to use Bloc with streams and concurrency](https://verygood.ventures/blog/how-to-use-bloc-with-streams-and-concurrency) and read `Blocs and streams` section

Comment: i already did that, i ended up with wrapping my custom scrollview with streambuilder to trigger rebuild everytime a new value add to my sink

Answer (score 2):

That `StreamController` you're creating in the `Chat` class is not the same instance as the one you're adding to in the Dio method. You're creating a stream, then listening to it, but never adding to that actual stream.

You need to listen to the stream that the Dio is actually updating.

Below is an incomplete example but should get you going in the right direction. The preferred way to listen to a Stream in bloc is to use `emit.forEach` then return a new state on each Stream update.

This requires that your Dio method returns a Stream or if there is a repository class in between, then have that return a Stream, that then gets passed into the stream argument of `emit.forEach`

```
class Chat extends Bloc<ChatEvent, ChatState> {
  Chat(this.chatUseCases, this.chat) : super(const SingleChatState()) {
    on<ChatEmitUploadList>(_emitUploadList);
    on<ChatInitStreamListener>(_onChatInitStreamListener); // adding this event

    add(ChatInitStreamListener()); // call this event from constructor
  }

  FutureOr<void> _onChatInitStreamListener(event, Emitter<ChatState> emit) {
    final fileStream = // stream from the Dio method

    emit.forEach(fileStream, onData: (FileDetails fileDetails) {
      // handle each stream update here and return a new ChatState
      // if no changes in state are required then `return state;`
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem i when you add the event    add(SingleChatEvent.emitUploadList(fileDetails: event)).on the construct of chat  there is not register of a method which implements SingleChatEvent. , there should have a method in the chat construct that implements the SingleChatEvent event.

Comment: i already implemented this method, this is not the problem

Comment: @YaserHesham. this is my  linkedin  : https://www.linkedin.com/in/mario-chita-548675136/ 


inbox me , i can help you